# Reusable tableview cells affecting each other without interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have been trying to make an app entirely programatically in Swift for the first time and have ran into a problem using UITableViews.
I have created a custom reusable cell I have called "exerciseCell" and in there is a UILabel a UIImageview and a UISwitch.

My problem is that when I select the switch on row 0 it is also switching on the switch on rows 3 and 6. This is the same for each cell, they affect about three cells each.
The purpose of this tableview is to be able to select which exercises you want a list of exercises but they each need to be able to be selected independently.

Here is the code for the cell:

```
class exerciseCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

var cellSelected:Bool = false

let excersiseLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textColor = UIColor.red
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    return label
}()
let excersiseImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

let thisSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let thisSwitch = UISwitch()
    thisSwitch.isOn = false
    thisSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return thisSwitch

}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(excersiseLabel)
    addSubview(excersiseImage)
    addSubview(thisSwitch)
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0": excersiseLabel]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-101-[v0(100)]-101-|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0": excersiseImage]))
   addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-120-[v0(100)]-120-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thisSwitch]))

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-12-[v0(30)]-8-[v1(100)]-12-[v2(30)]-12-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": excersiseLabel, "v1": excersiseImage, "v2": thisSwitch]))

}
```

}

Also the cellForRow is as follows:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var thisCell = UITableViewCell()

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "thirdCellID", for: indexPath) as! exerciseCell
        aCell.excersiseLabel.text = "\(mobility[indexPath.row])"
        aCell.thisSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        thisCell = aCell
    }
    return thisCell

}
```

How can I get the cells to respond to the user independently? I can provide more of my code if needed for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Since the cells are reused by the table view, they won't retain their switch settings. You will need an external construct to keep track of which cells are selected.

The cell will need to let your controller know when its switch has been toggled (possibly via delegation), at which point you'd update your (for instance) array of BOOLs.

Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you'll need some code to apply the correct values to the cell. Something like:

```
cell.switch.isOn = cellSwitchStates[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the common problem showing in uitableviewcell. The best way to solve this problem is to configure cell with Objects.

For example, in your case you need to show list of Exercise in Tableview. 
So, create one modal class for Exercise with a boolean variable (e.g. `var switchState: Bool`).

```
class Exercise: NSObject {

    var exerciseName : String?
    var switchState : Bool = false

    init (exerciseName : String?,switchState : Bool) {
        super.init()
        self.exerciseName = exerciseName
        self.switchState = switchState
    } 
}
```

Then populate an array of Exercise objects (e.g. `var exercises : [Exercise]`) with default switchState value false.

Then TableView numberofrows count taken from exercises array... return exercises.count,

In `cellForRowAt indexPath`
take correct exercise object from exercises array e.g.: `var exercise = exercises[indexpath.row]`,now we have correct object right? so create one method `fun configureCellWith(exercise:Exercise)` inside your custom cell (in your case cell will be aCell)
So call this cell method from cellForRowAt indexPath and pass our exercise object as parameter

**e.g.:** `aCell.configureCellWith(exercise)`
and your configureCellWith() method within exerciseCell should be like this

```
// Write this method within exerciseCell
func configureCellWith(exercise:Exercise) {

privateExercise = exercise // privateExercise is a private Variable for exerciseCell so please create private var privateExercise : Exercise in exerciseCell

thisSwitch.isOn = exercise.switchState 

}
```

Then Create one action method for your switch within the exerciseCell

```
thisSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("switchTriggered:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged );


func switchTriggered(sender: AnyObject) {

    let switch = sender as! UISwitch
    privateExercise.switchState = switch.isOn

}
```

Now Everything looks fine.. please do switch ON/OFF row 0 and check if it's affect others rows or not. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much @Aby, this has stopped them from affecting each other however if I scroll down in the tableview and then scroll back up the switch will return to the off position.
I may not of done the private variable correctly, it kept giving me errors regarding not assigning an exerciseName so I just initialised the name to "".

Comment: I think it's because the switchTriggered method isn't being recognised. I've put a print("Switch Triggered") in the func but it's never displayed. Is the selector style correct?